# AccessViolationException when calling C dll from C#

Tags: c#, marshalling

I'm trying to create a wrapper for a C dll to use it in C#. I don't have the source code of the dll.
I'm having problem using a method that gives me "System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt'" when executing. I tried to search online for the same problem but I didn't find what the problem with my code is.

The method that gives the problem is the following:

C:

```
L3B6_API L3B6_ERR_t STDCALL L3B6_ActivateBoot(int nodeid, unsigned cpunum, unsigned ms_timeout, const char * devicenames, A * dev_param);
```

the wrapper I created in C# is this:

```
[DllImport("L3B6.dll", EntryPoint = "L3B6_ActivateBoot")]
return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
static extern L3B6ErrorCode ActivateBoot(
                int nodeid,
                uint cpunum,
                uint msTimeout,
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
                string deviceNames,
                ref A devParams
                );
```

Where L3B6ErrorCode is an enum I created but it doesn't give any problem (I used it for other methods that work).
I think the problem is in the structure A. The original structure is like this:

```
struct A
{
    unsigned char blv;
    unsigned char cpunum;
    unsigned char nodeid;
    unsigned char hwverA;
    unsigned char hwverB;
    unsigned char hwverC;
    unsigned char hwverD;
    unsigned char cputype;
    unsigned char hwcode;
    B memini_devrec;
};

struct B
{
    unsigned hwCode;                       
    unsigned cpuCode;                      
    unsigned dualCPU;                      
    unsigned cpuNumber;                    
    unsigned internalFlashStart;           
    unsigned internalFlashEnd;             
    unsigned externalFlashAccess;          
    unsigned externalFlashStart;           
    unsigned externalFlashEnd;             
    unsigned isResetVectorSpecified;       
    unsigned resetVectors;                 
    char bootName[32];                     
    unsigned isS19toPhyConversionAllowed;  
    unsigned noFlashPaging;                
    char deviceName[32];                   
    char cpuName[32];                      
};
```

The corresponding structures I created are the following:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct A
    {
        public byte bootloaderversion;
        public byte cpuNum;
        public byte nodeId;
        public byte hwVerA;
        public byte hwVerB;
        public byte hwVerC;
        public byte hwVerD;
        public byte cpuType;
        public byte hwCode;
        public B meminiDeviceRecord;
    };

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct B
    {
        public uint hwCode;
        public uint cpuCode;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public bool dualCPU;
        public uint cpuNumber;
        public uint internalFlashStart;
        public uint internalFlashEnd;
        public uint externalFlashAccess;
        public uint externalFlashStart;
        public uint externalFlashEnd;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public bool isResetVectorSpecified;
        public uint resetVectors;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
        public string bootName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public bool isS19toPhyConversionAllowed;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public bool noFlashPaging;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
        public string deviceName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
        public string cpuName;
    };
```

I've used the structure B in another method that needed to fill it and didn't have any problem, so I suppose the problem is in the A structure, but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. I think the problem is that structure because also another method that takes that structure as parameter is giving me the same exception. I checked the size of the structs in C and C# and it is the same.

Comment: `unsigned` in C would usually mean a `ushort` in C#. Are you sure it's supposed to be 32-bit? Also, using `bool` is _probably_ a bad idea - it corresponds to Windows BOOL, a 32-bit value where false == 0 and true is everything else.

Comment: By the way, did you verify that the `B` data you got from the other method is correct? You can't rely on getting exceptions when the structs are wrong - there's plenty of problems that will not cause an exception. E.g. in your case, the only two things you're dereferencing are the strings in `deviceNames` and the pointer to struct `A`.

Comment: @Luaan I used `bool` because the documentation of the structure where I put it told that those fields were boolean values that are either 0 or 1. Yes, I checked the data I got in the B structure and it is correct, I'm sure that unsigned is 32-bit because some fields marked as unsigned can't fit in two bytes (the method is parsing data from a file, so I know which values it is meant to put in the B structure and there are also values like "0xFFAFF0" for resetVectors for example).

Comment: `StructLayout(... , Charset = Charset.ANSI)`

Comment: Have you considered using a c++/cli wrapper? It lets you do the type conversions yourself, and that might be easier when you have complicated structures.

Comment: @JonasH no, I didn't even know about it until you mentioned it. I will look at it, thank you.

Comment: @Charlieface adding it didn't help, but I don't think the problem is in the strings since the structure that contains them (structure B) is filled correctly by another method that uses only the B structure and not the A one.

Comment: Pretty sure it is ANSI not Unicode. You should also try `ushort` instead of `uint` for all those `B` fields. `unisgned` in C normally refers to 16-bit. Is `memini_devrec` perhaps actually a `*` pointer?

Comment: @Charlieface regarding the unsigned being 16-bit please refer to the answer I gave to Luaan above. I checked but `memini_devrec` is not a pointer. Ok, I can leave the CharSet specified.

Comment: I saw that, but have you actually tried 16-bit? It's possible you've misinterpreted something

Comment: @Charlieface I just tried it, the exception it's still there and moreover the method that previously was working now returns inconsistent values in the struct B (like cropped strings for example).

Comment: Sounds like there is some weird `typedef`ing going on here. I suggest you follow through every C typename to see where it goes. I wonder also if the structs are packed or padded

Comment: The declarations are fine.  A basic way to check is to verify that sizeof(A) in C == Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(A)) in C#, 160 bytes in both.  The only oddball I see is "devicenames", a plural word for a parameter that can only store a single string.  *Might* be a single string that stores multiple zero-terminated character strings, no [MarshalAs] for that.  Contact the owner of this native DLL to verify.